# IOS Local Notifications not working with PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, notifications

I'm having trouble with displaying local notifications in my iOS PhoneGap-app. I have tried both the Katzer Local Notifications plugin (https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications#schedule-local-notifications) and the Wizcorp local notifications plugin (https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-plugin-localNotifications) but neither works for me. After installing both plugins I can access their respective JavaScript objects and with the Wizcorp plugin I can even manipulate the application badge, but I cant seem to add a local notification. This makes me believe that the problem lies elsewhere in my application/installation.

I've tried both plugins on both the ios emulator and the Phonegap developer app.

EDIT:
I am currently just trying to get this working with the plugin example code:

```
    var now                  = new Date().getTime(),
    _60_seconds_from_now = new Date(now + 60*1000);
window.plugin.notification.local.add({
    id:      1,
    title:   'Reminder',
    message: 'Dont forget to buy some flowers.',
    repeat:  'weekly',
    date:    _60_seconds_from_now
});
```

Comment: share the javascript code you are using to register a notification

Comment: Added code to the original question. Just trying to get the sample code to work

Comment: you've added cordova.js right! Put this code inside device ready function, or in a function which fires after device ready is fired. If that plugin is correctly installed, it should work.

Comment: This code fires after device ready event. The plugins are working (application badge works etc), i just cant get the local notifications working.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that you have registered your app for local notifications. This is not done automatically when you add the plugin.

For example (in the app delegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method):

```
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:
            [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:
                UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
```

Comment: You sir are my personal hero. I searched 40 years for that solution. Thanks!

Comment: Where should one do this within the cordova app?